# How to scroll text output in Java?

Tags: java, terminal, less-unix

Say I have a terminal with 30 lines of height.

And say I have a loop that outputs 100 lines of output

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Is there a way I can output the first 30 lines, show text that says "Press enter to continue output...", show the next 30 lines when the user presses enter, etc?

I want to do this in the easiest manner possible.  If I can use `less` somehow, that would be excellent.

---

### Update

This needs to be implemented in the Java source code. The following is not a suitable solution:

```
java program | less'
```

Also, I will need to programmatically get the height of whatever terminal it is executed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either pass `tput cols` to your java program as a command line arg or system property (java -DTermHeight=`tput cols`) or fetch it during runtime using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tput cols")`

Store that value in a variable `height`. Now

```
   height = (height==0?30:height);
    for(int i=1; i<=100; i++) {
        if (i % height== 0) {
            System.out.println("Press enter to continue output...");
            System.in.read();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Comment: Marking this as accepted answer for providing means of getting terminal height using Java. Giving +1 to other answers.

Comment: I am always getting '80' when running tput cols in Java, even though the same command in my terminal gives me a greater value. I am using JDK 1.7u51

Answer (score 2):

With **less**:

```
java program | less
```

or

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    if( i % 30 == 0) {
       System.out.println("Press enter to continue output...");
       System.in.read();
    }    
    System.out.println(i);   
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how I'd use `tput cols`? I'm sort of a Java noob.

Comment: @macek: Get the height of the screen from `tput` and pass it as parameter to java apps. Read `man tput`.

Answer (score 2):

Within Java:

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    if (i % 30 == 0) {
        System.out.println("Press enter to continue output...");
        r.readLine();
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: here `30` is statically coded. How can I dynamically get the height of the terminal?